# Change flat XML structure to nested structure using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to transform a flat xml struture into a nested xml structure based on grouping on employeeNumber value in the source xml. I have tried this using xslt 1.0 with the help of xsl:key but it is not working properly. Please help me to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Input xml

```
<XxhrPiEmpcompOutIntCollection>
          <XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt>
            <employeeNumber>
                200000562
            </employeeNumber>
            <competencyName>
                Comp1
            </competencyName>
            <proficiencyLevel>
                Prof1
            </proficiencyLevel>
            <compDateTo>
                16-NOV-12
            </compDateTo>
          </XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt>

           <XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt>
            <employeeNumber>
                200000562
            </employeeNumber>
            <competencyName>
                Comp2
            </competencyName>
            <proficiencyLevel>
                Prof2
            </proficiencyLevel>
            <compDateTo>
                16-NOV-12
            </compDateTo>
          </XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt>
          <XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt>
            <employeeNumber>
                200000574
            </employeeNumber>
            <competencyName>
                Comp2
            </competencyName>
            <proficiencyLevel>
                Prof2
            </proficiencyLevel>
            <compDateTo>
                16-NOV-12
            </compDateTo>
          </XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt>

        </XxhrPiEmpcompOutIntCollection>
```

Target xml

```
<EmployeeCompetencyRequest>
        <EmployeeNumber>200000562</EmployeeNumber>
        <Competencies>
            <Competency>
                <Name>Comp1</Name>
                <ProficiencyLevel>Prof1</ProficiencyLevel>
                <EndDate>16-NOV-12</EndDate>
            </Competency>
            <Competency>
                <Name>Comp2</Name>
                <ProficiencyLevel>Prof2</ProficiencyLevel>
                <EndDate>16-NOV-12</EndDate>
            </Competency>
        </Competencies>
        <EmployeeNumber>200000574</EmployeeNumber>
            <Competencies>
                <Competency>
                    <Name>Comp2</Name>
                    <ProficiencyLevel>Prof2</ProficiencyLevel>
                    <EndDate>16-NOV-12</EndDate>
                </Competency>
        </Competencies>
    </<EmployeeCompetencyRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kOutIntByENum" match="XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt" use="employeeNumber"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <EmployeeCompetencyRequest><xsl:apply-templates/></EmployeeCompetencyRequest>
 </xsl:template>    

 <xsl:template match=
 "XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt
   [generate-id()
   =
    generate-id(key('kOutIntByENum', employeeNumber)[1])]">
  <EmployeeNumber>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(employeeNumber)"/>
  </EmployeeNumber>
  <Competencies>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="comp"
         select="key('kOutIntByENum', employeeNumber)"/>
  </Competencies>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt" mode="comp">
  <Competency>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="comp" select="*[not(self::employeeNumber)]"/>
  </Competency>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="competencyName" mode="comp">
   <Name><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></Name>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="proficiencyLevel" mode="comp">
   <ProficiencyLevel><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></ProficiencyLevel>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="compDateTo" mode="comp">
   <EndDate><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></EndDate>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<XxhrPiEmpcompOutIntCollection>
          <XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt>
            <employeeNumber>
                200000562
            </employeeNumber>
            <competencyName>
                Comp1
            </competencyName>
            <proficiencyLevel>
                Prof1
            </proficiencyLevel>
            <compDateTo>
                16-NOV-12
            </compDateTo>
          </XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt>

           <XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt>
            <employeeNumber>
                200000562
            </employeeNumber>
            <competencyName>
                Comp2
            </competencyName>
            <proficiencyLevel>
                Prof2
            </proficiencyLevel>
            <compDateTo>
                16-NOV-12
            </compDateTo>
          </XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt>
          <XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt>
            <employeeNumber>
                200000574
            </employeeNumber>
            <competencyName>
                Comp2
            </competencyName>
            <proficiencyLevel>
                Prof2
            </proficiencyLevel>
            <compDateTo>
                16-NOV-12
            </compDateTo>
          </XxhrPiEmpcompOutInt>
</XxhrPiEmpcompOutIntCollection>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<EmployeeCompetencyRequest>
   <EmployeeNumber>200000562</EmployeeNumber>
   <Competencies>
      <Competency>
         <Name>Comp1</Name>
         <ProficiencyLevel>Prof1</ProficiencyLevel>
         <EndDate>16-NOV-12</EndDate>
      </Competency>
      <Competency>
         <Name>Comp2</Name>
         <ProficiencyLevel>Prof2</ProficiencyLevel>
         <EndDate>16-NOV-12</EndDate>
      </Competency>
   </Competencies>
   <EmployeeNumber>200000574</EmployeeNumber>
   <Competencies>
      <Competency>
         <Name>Comp2</Name>
         <ProficiencyLevel>Prof2</ProficiencyLevel>
         <EndDate>16-NOV-12</EndDate>
      </Competency>
   </Competencies>
</EmployeeCompetencyRequest>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Muenchian Grouping Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** and **[modes](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#modes)**.